# Webpack 4 Multi-Part library and sub-libraries

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, commonjs, es6-modules

**Overview**

I'am developing a javascript library with Webpack4 & ES6 called: "shared-services" which contains different sub-folders. Each of these subfolders represent a "local sub-library" inside which could contain:

- references to other 3rd libraries like `lodash`, etc but also
- references to the methods of the other "sub-folders or sub-libraries"

**Example**

I've made an example of my problem and pushed it to github: https://github.com/iarroyo5/multi-part-library-webpack. Helpfully it should be as simple as follow the `Readme` file in order to execute it :)

**Issues**

1. In my example I've named the *"shared-services"* library as *"multi-part-library-webpack"*. There are two "sub-folders": `api` and `path`. The goal is that both `sub-folders/sub-libraries` would be available in this way:

   `import { API_URL, getApiUrl } from '@iarroyo/multi-part-library-webpack/api";`
   `import { getUserPath } from '@iarroyo/multi-part-library-webpack/path";`

In the provided example I've already got my goal!! ...the Webpack output are 3 files:

1. `index.js` --> contains all the methods from `api` and `path` as `apiLib` and `pathLib`
2. `api.js` --> contains `api` methods
3. `path.js` ---> contains `path` methods and **`api` methods** :(

[image]

but my **big unresolved problem** comes of this ^. Because of some of the methods of `api` are being imported into the `path` library (each folder must be a `sub-library` itself and they could be used inside the other folders) the webpack `path.js` file contains the `api` sub-folder entirely.

In the example `path` is using `lodash`, but third libraries are not being exported because I've added them to the `externals` Webpack option, so this at least is working.

2. This is not ideal, and there is another big problem:

   `import { API_URL, getApiUrl } from '@iarroyo/multi-part-library-webpack/api";`

^ this is completely fine and it is returning the correct values as theses named imports are from `api`, but... I can also do this:

```
import { API_URL, getApiUrl } from '@iarroyo/multi-part-library-webpack/path";
```

because all the methods from the `api` are inside of `path`... the only difference is that the value of these methods/variables are `undefined`... so this solution is not ideal at all, as some could try to use that `methods`, `variables` and the `path` library should throw an exception like `invalid method...`

**Applied Insights**

1. I've tried adding each *sub-folder* as external too, in that way I was thinking maybe Webpack will recognise that they are external of each other... but this doesn't help.
2. I've added the option `"sideEffects": false` in order to enable `Tree Shaking` with Webpack 4, but obviously it is not working at all. I read about of `tree-shaking` doesn't work transpiling the code with `babel-loader` but I am not pretty sure if this has been solved in webpack4 (seems like the official webpack released log says yes... but!!). 
   In any case, I've also removed it from the `webpack-config` and gave it a try and `tree-shaking` is not working either... (I need `babel-loader` for my final library, so this is a requirement)
3. I've tried with `DllPlugin` and I've reviewed all the [Webpack examples](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples) to try to get some fresh ideas, but splitting into `chunks` files I think is not a solution for ¯this reason:
   [image]

As you could see, using the `optimization.splitChunks` options of webpack4 I have reusable code, but the problem is that when I am generating my final `commonjs2` library I can't access my `sub-libraries` like

```
import { API_URL, getApiUrl } from '@iarroyo/multi-part-library-webpack/api";
import { getUserPath } from '@iarroyo/multi-part-library-webpack/path";
```

**this doesn't work anymore!! :(** because of now all the methods are in `commons-index-path.js` and `commons-api-index-path.j and`api.js`and`path.js` are minified files that when I'm trying to access the methods they are throwing this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at /Users/inakiarroyo/workspace/spartancode/export-library/dist/index.js:1:1011
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/inakiarroyo/workspace/spartancode/export-library/dist/index.js:1:1163)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/inakiarroyo/workspace/spartancode/export-library/dev/es6-lib.js:3:25)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
```

This post [window is not defined when consuming webpack multi-part-library sample files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304790/window-is-not-defined-when-consuming-webpack-multi-part-library-sample-files) could be related.

I was expecting maybe webpack will save references to my methods and I will be able to use `api.js` and `path.js`, but again :(

**Possible Solutions**

1. The only way I think it could work is having one `package.json` per "sub-folder" into the `"multi-part-library-webpack"` running these "children-webpack" runners in order to generated each library and have another "parent-webpack" runner which will use as webpack `entry` each sub file generated for each "child-webpack"... **but honestly this sound like a mess solution**.
2. Is really possible what I am trying to do with `Webpack4` ?
3. Does anyone know if this is possible with [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) ?

Comment: One of the possible solutions is the use of https://lernajs.io/ integrating it with yarn workspaces.